# Trying to Get Running Total to Work

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that works perfectly for combining ElapsedTime that is considered Non-Productive when NonProductive = 1.  However, I have been trying to get a running total to work. This the main query that totals by ReportNo for each day:

```
Select SUM(CASE
           When NonProductive = 1 Then ElapsedTime
           Else 0
           End) 
            From DailyOperations
           Where (DailyOperations.WellID = 'ZCQ-5') AND (DailyOperations.JobID = 'Original')  and (ReportNo = 9)
```

ReportNo = 9 is the first Reportno that has NonProductive time which is 4. The next is ReportNo = 14. It has 5.5 hours of NonProductive time. So when I run ReportNo 14 I am hoping to see a total of 9.5 and nothing else. Below is the query that I am using for my running total but it is listing all of the Non-Productive time. So Instead of getting just 9.5 for ReportNo 14 I am also getting a running total for each instance of NonProductive time in the report:

```
SELECT (ElapsedTime),(Reportno),NonProductive,
SUM(ElapsedTime) OVER (PARTITION BY NonProductive ORDER BY REPORTNO ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
AS RUNNINGTOTAL
FROM            dbo.DailyOperations
WHERE  (NonProductive IN(1)) and  (WellID = 'ZCQ-5') AND (JobID = 'Original')  

Group by ReportNo,ElapsedTime,NonProductive

Order by ReportNo
```

This gives me:

```
ReportNo      RUNNINGTOTAL
     9               4
     14              6
     14             9.5
```

What I want is:

```
ReportNo      RUNNINGTOTAL
     9               4
     14              9.5
```

Comment: Sound like you need a where clause

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
SELECT Reportno,NonProductive,
       SUM(SUM(ElapsedTime)) OVER (PARTITION BY NonProductive ORDER BY REPORTNO) AS RUNNINGTOTAL
FROM dbo.DailyOperations o
WHERE NonProductive IN (1) and WellID = 'ZCQ-5' AND JobID = 'Original') 
GROUP BY ReportNo
ORDER BY ReportNo;
```

Notes:

- The `GROUP BY` defines each row that you want in the result set.  Hence, you only want `ReportNo` in it.
- When combining window functions and aggregation functions, you sometimes end up with strange looking constructs such as `SUM(SUM())`.
- The windowing clause is unnecessary.  What you have is basically the default when you use `ORDER BY` (actually, the default is `RANGE BETWEEN`, but `ReportId` is unique so the two are equivalent).

Comment: This is great! Thank you very much. I never would have figured out Sum(Sum. It seems simple now but typically everything does until you see it! You are spectacular!